# export xls limits

Tags: visualforce, data-export

I have to implement an export of a custom table to an Excel (xls) file. I have created a custom Visualforce page and set
 `"contentType =" application / vnd.ms-excel # {! TableExcel.Name} .xls "` and everything works correctly!

I do not have real data, so I'm afraid there will be problems when we go to production. What are the limits that I have to prepare for or catch? I only found limits on the pdf renderer:

1. The maximum response size when creating a PDF file to be less than 15 MB before being rendered as a PDF file.
2. The maximum file size for a generated PDF file is 60 MB
3. The maximum total size of images included in a generated PDF is 30 MB

Are these limits also valid for xls files? 
Are there any other important things to consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PDF limits have absolutely no bearing on other types of file generation. You'll want to read more in [Best Practices for Improving Visualforce Performance](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_performance.htm). In general, the most important limit for you is that there is a 15 MB maximum response size. Considering the fact that there's also the 6 MB heap limit, you will need to use apex:iteration to generate the data to minimize the amount of heap you use.

You'll also want to set the read-only attribute to give you up to 10,000 rows of iteration. Even then, without careful planning, you won't be able to export more than 10,000 rows this way. You'll be even further limited if each row contains more than 600 characters, because at that point, you're going to reach heap limits. Ideally, you should limit your response to about 1,000-2,000 rows as a decent safety margin against governor limits.